# Multiple sections in Content Block for Drupal

Tags: drupal

How to create multiple sections in Content block in Drupal?

When a user visits my homepage, a mainpage will be displayed; this page will contain a few sections at the middle panel. One of these sections would be a news update section, another would be a video channel, much like how [mtv UK](http://www.mtv.co.uk/) is looking in the middle portion of the homepage.

[http://lh6.ggpht.com/_SDci0Pf3tzU/Sd7SEwzEbhI/AAAAAAAAEqc/ROuP7fXkRSk/s400/section.png](http://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/i8bt_NIExHjD2oEXvULrpA?feat=embedwebsite)

What modules are needed to create this kind of website layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That site is using mainly [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels), and [Nice Menus](http://drupal.org/project/nice_menus)

Answer (score 1):

A combination of the Views and Panels modules would be able to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to try the composite layout module (which I find simpler to use & theme than Panels) : http://drupal.org/project/composite (unfortunately not yet available for D7)