# Show YouTube video in a Drupal Section

Tags: drupal

Thanks to [the help of SOers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736755/multiple-sections-in-content-block-for-drupal), now I can create a few sections in a Drupal page using [Panels module](http://drupal.org/project/panels). I want to embed a YouTube video inside one of the section, anyway to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the module Embedded Media Field from drupal.org.

Advantage of using this module is that it validates the structure of the embed code text to ensure valid YouTube link. Beats coding that yourself.

Get and install module, enable it. Need to enable the 'Embedded Media Field' and the 'Embedded Video' options in the CCK group of modules.

Then in the 'Content Management' there is a 'Embedded Media Field configuration' link.
On that page expand the 'Embedded Video Field' section and then the 'YouTube Configuration' option. Tick that want to 'Allow content from YouTube'.

Now you can add an Embedded Video field to an Content Type and if required theme it.

Answer (score 3):

Paste the "embed" code directly into the node body and set the Input format to be Filtered HTML. No need for any additional modules.

Comment: I think he'll want to use Full HTML as the filter, <embed> is normally stripped from Filtered HTML.